# Looping through worksheets in a workbook and consolidating each workbook in to a worksheet in the master workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have search and search for an answer to my code issue but I cant find any. I will be very grateful if someone can take a look at my code. At the moment, I have several large workbooks for data for each country. Each workbook has more that 5 work sheets. I want to consolidate the workbooks into a master file. First, I wan to copy and paste all worksheets under one work sheet in the master workbook and name it all by the country. Right now, my code is only able to consolidate one country at a time which makes it very slow. also the loop worksheet seems to the failing. It creates only one country worksheet. If I put in multiple country names, only the last country workbook gets consolidated. Something is missing but I cant seem to figure it out. Thank you so much!!!! Below is my code:

```
Sub consolidate()

   Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

   Dim folderPath As String
   Dim Filename As String
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim NewSht As Worksheet
   Dim FindRng As Range
   Dim PasteRow As Long

   Dim countryname As String
   Dim LastRow, Rowlast, Rowlast2 As Long
   Const fr As Long = 2
   Dim i As Long
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim wx As Worksheet
   Set wx = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Countryname")
   Rowlast = wx.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row 'selects list of country workbook I want to consolidate. e.g I could have Germany, usa, china
   Rowlast2 = wx.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row 'selects list of tabs for each country workbook I want to consolidate, e.g I want for every country listed above, that sheet names 1, 2, 3, 4 be consolidated and put in new worksheets in the masterfile

   With wx
      For LastRow = fr To Rowlast
         If .Cells(LastRow, "B").Value <> "" Then
            countryname = .Cells(LastRow, "B").Value
            ' set master workbook
            Set Masterwb = Workbooks("ebele_test.xlsm")
            folderPath = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                  "Please enter only folder path in this format as C:\Users\...  Exclude the file name", _
            Title:="InputBox Method", Type:=2) 'Type:=2 = text

            If folderPath = "False" Or IsError(folderPath) Then 'If Cancel is clicked on Input Box exit sub

               MsgBox "Incorrect Input, Please paste correct folder path"
               Exit Sub
               'On Error GoTo 0

            End If
            If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Dim str As String
            str = "Screener_User_Template-"

            Filename = Dir(folderPath & str & countryname & "*.xlsx")
            Do While Filename <> ""
               Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)

               If Len(wb.Name) > 253 Then
                  MsgBox "Sheet's name can be up to 253 characters long, shorten the Excel file name"
                  wb.Close False
                  GoTo Exit_Loop
               Else
                  ' add a new sheet with the file's name (remove the extension)
                  With Masterwb
                     Dim isLastSheet As Boolean
                     Dim ci, rows1 As Integer
                     Dim row As Long
                     rows1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                     For ci = rows1 To 1 Step (-1)
                        If (isLastSheet) = False Then
                           Set NewSht = Masterwb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(ci)) 'Place sheet at the end.
                           NewSht.Cells(1, 1) = "Identifier"
                           NewSht.Cells(1, 2) = "Company Name"
                           NewSht.Cells(1, 3) = "Country of Incorporation"
                           NewSht.Name = countryname
                        End If
                     Next ci
                  End With

               End If

               ' loop through all sheets in opened wb

               For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
                  For i = 2 To Rowlast2
                     If sh.Name = wx.Cells(i, "C").Value And NewSht.Name = countryname Then
                        ' get the first empty row in the new sheet

                        Set FindRng = NewSht.Cells.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

                        If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' If find is successful
                           PasteRow = FindRng.row + 1
                        Else ' find was unsuccessfull > new empty sheet, should paste at the second row
                           PasteRow = 2
                        End If

                        Dim rng As Range
                        Set rng = sh.Range(sh.Cells(3, "A"), sh.Cells(150000, "M"))
                        rng.Copy

                        NewSht.Range("A" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                     End If
                     Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears the clipboard
                  Next i
               Next sh
               wb.Close False
Exit_Loop:
               Set wb = Nothing
               Filename = Dir
            Loop
         End If
      Next LastRow
   End With
   '0:  Exit Sub
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to read through. Can you explain the general steps your code aims to complete

Comment: `wx.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row` this looks wrong, I think you want `wx.Range("B" & wx.Rows.Count).End(xlup).row`, same for column "C"

Comment: @O.PAL: 'Application.Rows.Count', 'Rows.Count' and 'wx.Rows.Count' all return the same number. To conclude: 'Rows.Count' is fine. You're right about 'xlUp', though.

Comment: There is not enough info here for anyone to provide a solution to a logic error. We can call out other syntax errors or possible confusion in coding like your line  `Dim LastRow, Rowlast, Rowlast2 As Long`. You are actually only declaring `Rowlast2` as long. The first two variables are not specified and are defaulting to type `Variant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It's a Mess

This is **not a solution**, just a work in progress which I cannot continue due to lack of information and knowledge. It could help you to finish what you started. It would be a shame to quit after you have invested so much time in it. If you provide some answers from the questions in the code someone else might help you finish it. The questions are by no means ironic, they're serious questions that I cannot answer for sure.

The code should be safe, but just **don't save anything** not to lose data.

I would suggest you somehow split such a code into several and ask several questions to get answers in the future.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

  Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

  ' ThisWorkbook
  Const cStrCountry As String = "CountryName"
  Const cLngRow1 As Long = 2
  ' Tip:  To use columns either as string or as integer declare them as Variant.
  Const cVntColCountries As Variant = "B"
  Const cVntColTabs As Variant = "C"

  Const cStrTemplate = "Screener_User_Template-"
  Const cStrMaster As String = "ebele_test.xlsm"
  Const cStrExt = ".xlsx"

  ' New Worksheet in Master Workbook
  Const cStrNewHeader1 = "Identifier"
  Const cStrNewHeader2 = "Company Name"
  Const cStrNewHeader3 = "Country of Incorporation"

  ' Each Worksheet in Each Workbook
  Const cLngFirstRow As Long = 3
  Const cLngLastRow As Long = 150000
  ' Tip:  To use columns either as string or as integer declare them as Variant.
  Const cVntFirstCol As Variant = "A"
  Const cVntLastCol As Variant = "M"

  ' MsgBox
  Dim strMsg1 As String
    strMsg1 = "Please enter only folder path in this format as " _
            & "C:\Users\... Exclude the file name"
  Dim strMsg2 As String
    strMsg2 = "Incorrect Input. Please paste correct folder path."
  Dim strMsg3 As String
    strMsg3 = "Sheet's name can only be up to 253 characters long. " _
            & "Shorten the Excel file name."

  ' Workbooks
'  ThisWorkbook
  Dim ojbWbEach As Workbook     ' Workbook Looper
  Dim objWbMaster As Workbook   ' Master Workbook

  ' Worksheets
'  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets (cStrCountry)
  Dim objWsEach As Worksheet    ' Worksheet Looper
  Dim objWsNew As Worksheet     ' New Worksheet

  ' Arrays Pasted From Ranges
  Dim vntCountries As Variant   ' List of Countries
  Dim vntTabs As Variant        ' List of Tabs

  ' Ranges
  Dim objRngEmpty As Range      ' New Sheet Paste Cell

  ' Rows
  Dim lngPasteRow As Long       ' New Sheet Paste Row
  Dim lngCountries As Long      ' Countries Counter
  Dim lngTabs As Long           ' Tabs Counter

  ' Strings
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strCountry As String

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrCountry)

    ' Paste list of countries from column cVntColCountries into array
    vntCountries = .Range(.Cells(cLngRow1, cVntColCountries), _
        .Cells(Rows.Count, cVntColCountries).End(xlUp)).Value2

    ' Paste list of tabs from column cVntColTabs into array
    vntTabs = .Range(.Cells(cLngRow1, cVntColTabs), _
        .Cells(Rows.Count, cVntColTabs).End(xlUp)).Value2

  End With
  ' The data is in arrays instead of ranges.

  ' 1. According to the following line the workbook objWbMaster is already open.
  '    Is that true?
  Set objWbMaster = Workbooks(cStrMaster)

  For lngCountries = LBound(vntCountries) To UBound(vntCountries)

    If vntCountries(lngCountries, 1) <> "" Then

        strCountry = vntCountries(lngCountries, 1)

        ' Determine the path to search for files in.
        strPath = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=strMsg1, _
          Title:="InputBox Method", Type:=2) ' Type:=2 = text

        ' When Cancel is clicked in Input Box ... Exit Sub
        If strPath = "False" Or IsError(strPath) Then
          MsgBox strMsg2
          Exit Sub
        End If
        If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        strFile = Dir(strPath & cStrTemplate & strCountry & "*" & cStrExt)
        ' VBA Help: Dir returns the first file name that matches pathname. To
        '           get any additional file names that match pathname, call Dir
        '           again with no arguments. When no more file names match, Dir
        '           returns a zero-length string ("").
        ' i.e. The approach is correct!
        Do While strFile <> ""

          Set ojbWbEach = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)

          ' 2. When would this ever happen?
          If Len(ojbWbEach.Name) <= 253 Then
            ' Add a new sheet with the file's name (remove the extension)
            With objWbMaster
              ' 3. Isn't the blnLastSheet always False. What should it be doing?
              Dim blnLastSheet As Boolean
              Dim intSheetsCounter As Integer
              Dim intSheets As Integer
              intSheets = .Worksheets.Count
              ' 4. Why parentheses in ... Step (-1)?
              For intSheetsCounter = intSheets To 1 Step -1
                ' 5. Why parentheses in (blnLastSheet)?
                If (blnLastSheet) = False Then
                  ' Place sheet at the end.
                  Set objWsNew = .Worksheets _
                      .Add(After:=.Worksheets(intSheetsCounter))
                  With objWsNew
                    .Cells(1, 1) = cStrNewHeader1
                    .Cells(1, 2) = cStrNewHeader2
                    .Cells(1, 3) = cStrNewHeader3
                    .Name = strCountry
                  End With
                End If
              Next
            End With
           Else
            MsgBox strMsg3
            ojbWbEach.Close False
            GoTo Exit_Loop
          End If

          ' Loop through all worksheets in ojbWbEach.
          For Each objWsEach In ojbWbEach.Worksheets
            With objWsEach

              For lngTabs = LBound(vntTabs) To UBound(vntTabs)
                If .Name = vntTabs(lngTabs) _
                    And objWsNew.Name = strCountry Then

                  ' Get the first empty row in the new sheet
                  Set objRngEmpty = objWsNew.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

                  ' 6. I don't think that this is necessary because you added
                  '    the headers to the New sheet so it will find the first
                  '    row. Or am I missing something?
                  If Not objRngEmpty Is Nothing Then
                    ' If find is successful.
                    lngPasteRow = objRngEmpty.row + 1
                   Else
                    ' Find was unsuccessfull > new empty sheet.
                    ' Should paste at the second row.
                    lngPasteRow = cLngRow1
                  End If

                  ' if I'm right, delete all starting from "Set objRngEmpty ..."
                  ' and delete "Dim objRngEmpty as Range" and use the following
                  ' line:
'                  lngPasteRow = objWsNew.Cells.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row + 1

                  ' Pasting a range into a same sized range is much faster than
                  ' looping or copy/pasting.
                  objWsNew.Range(.Cells(lngPasteRow, cVntFirstCol), _
                      .Cells(cLngLastRow + lngPasteRow - cLngFirstRow, _
                      cVntLastCol)) = _
                  .Range(.Cells(cLngFirstRow, cVntFirstCol), _
                      .Cells(cLngLastRow, cVntLastCol)).Value2

                End If
              Next

              .Close False

            End With
          Next

Exit_Loop:
          Set ojbWbEach = Nothing
          strFile = Dir
        Loop
      End If
    Next lngCountries

  Set objWsEach = Nothing
  Set objWsNew = Nothing
  Set objWbEach = Nothing
  Set objWbMaster = Nothing

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Its a mess and I should have cleaned up some of the dead codes before posting it but I was afraid that I will break something after working on it the whole day and it was finally consolidating at 2am in the morning (German time) even though it wasn't working exactly as I intended. I was going to just take my "half bread" and run with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clean up. To answer some of your questions. Q1: Yes it is open. It is the master workbook with a work sheet open in it with list of countries and list of tab names. Q2: It is surprising but sometimes the location folder names are so long, it is insane. I am in Germany after all. we use long names for things.sorry! Q 3,4 and 5: I don't remember why I did that. I think I wrote a code and modified it. Q6: That was a leftover code. At first it pasted all the headings from each sheet and I didn't want that. Thank you so much! I will let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for the clean up. I made some modifications to your code and corrected some error but for some reason, it is only able to consolidate 7 countries after which excel crashes. See the code I am running below: Do you think you can find the issue?

Option Explicit

```
Sub Consolidate()

  Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

  ' ThisWorkbook
  Const cStrCountry As String = "CountryName"
  Const cLngRow1 As Long = 2
  ' Tip:  To use columns either as string or as integer declare them as Variant.
  Const cVntColCountries As Variant = "B"
  Const cVntColTabs As Variant = "C"

  Const cStrTemplate = "Screener_User_Template-"
  Const cStrMaster As String = "ebele_test.xlsm"
  Const cStrExt = ".xlsx"

  ' New Worksheet in Master Workbook
  Const cStrNewHeader1 = "Identifier"
  Const cStrNewHeader2 = "Company Name"
  Const cStrNewHeader3 = "Country of Incorporation"

  ' Each Worksheet in Each Workbook
  Const cLngFirstRow As Long = 3
  Const cLngLastRow As Long = 150000
  ' Tip:  To use columns either as string or as integer declare them as Variant.
  Const cVntFirstCol As Variant = "A"
  Const cVntLastCol As Variant = "M"

  ' MsgBox
  Dim strMsg1 As String
    strMsg1 = "Please enter only folder path in this format as " _
            & "C:\Users\... Exclude the file name"
  Dim strMsg2 As String
    strMsg2 = "Incorrect Input. Please paste correct folder path."
  Dim strMsg3 As String
    strMsg3 = "Sheet's name can only be up to 253 characters long. " _
            & "Shorten the Excel file name."

  ' Workbooks
'  ThisWorkbook
  Dim ojbWbEach As Workbook     ' Workbook Looper
  Dim objWbMaster As Workbook   ' Master Workbook

  ' Worksheets
'  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets (cStrCountry)
  Dim objWsEach As Worksheet    ' Worksheet Looper
  Dim objWsNew As Worksheet     ' New Worksheet

  ' Arrays Pasted From Ranges
  Dim vntCountries As Variant   ' List of Countries
  Dim vntTabs As Variant        ' List of Tabs

  ' Ranges
  Dim objRngEmpty As Range      ' New Sheet Paste Cell

  ' Rows
  Dim lngPasteRow As Long       ' New Sheet Paste Row
  Dim lngCountries As Long      ' Countries Counter
  Dim lngTabs As Long           ' Tabs Counter

  ' Strings
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strCountry As String

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrCountry)

    ' Paste list of countries from column cVntColCountries into array
    vntCountries = .Range(.Cells(cLngRow1, cVntColCountries), _
        .Cells(Rows.Count, cVntColCountries).End(xlUp)).Value2

    ' Paste list of tabs from column cVntColTabs into array
    vntTabs = .Range(.Cells(cLngRow1, cVntColTabs), _
        .Cells(Rows.Count, cVntColTabs).End(xlUp)).Value2

  End With
  ' The data is in arrays instead of ranges.

  ' 1. According to the following line the workbook objWbMaster is already open.
  '    Is that true? yeah, but I moved the strpath up because I want it to be inputed once
  Set objWbMaster = Workbooks(cStrMaster)
        ' Determine the path to search for files in.         
          strPath = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=strMsg1, _
          Title:="InputBox Method", Type:=2) ' Type:=2 = text
  '
  For lngCountries = LBound(vntCountries) To UBound(vntCountries)
       If vntCountries(lngCountries, 1) <> "" And strPath <> "" Then

        strCountry = vntCountries(lngCountries, 1)


        ' When Cancel is clicked in Input Box ... Exit Sub
        If strPath = "False" Or IsError(strPath) Then
          MsgBox strMsg2
          Exit Sub
        End If

        If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        strFile = Dir(strPath & cStrTemplate & strCountry & "*" & cStrExt)
        ' VBA Help: Dir returns the first file name that matches pathname. To
        '           get any additional file names that match pathname, call Dir
        '           again with no arguments. When no more file names match, Dir
        '           returns a zero-length string ("").
        ' i.e. The approach is correct!
        Do While strFile <> ""

          Set ojbWbEach = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)

          ' 2. When would this ever happen?
          If Len(ojbWbEach.Name) <= 253 Then
            ' Add a new sheet with the file's name (remove the extension)
            With objWbMaster
              ' 3. Isn't the blnLastSheet always False. What should it be doing?
              Dim blnLastSheet As Boolean
              Dim intSheetsCounter As Integer
              Dim intSheets As Integer
              intSheets = .Worksheets.Count
              ' 4. Why parentheses in ... Step (-1)?
              For intSheetsCounter = intSheets To 1 Step -1
                ' 5. Why parentheses in (blnLastSheet)?
                If blnLastSheet = False Then
                  ' Place sheet at the end.
                  Set objWsNew = .Worksheets _
                      .Add(After:=.Worksheets(intSheetsCounter))
                  With objWsNew
                    .Cells(1, 1) = cStrNewHeader1
                    .Cells(1, 2) = cStrNewHeader2
                    .Cells(1, 3) = cStrNewHeader3

                  End With
                End If
              Next
            End With
           Else
            MsgBox strMsg3
            ojbWbEach.Close False
            GoTo Exit_Loop
          End If

          ' Loop through all worksheets in ojbWbEach.
          For Each objWsEach In ojbWbEach.Worksheets
            With objWsEach

              For lngTabs = LBound(vntTabs) To UBound(vntTabs)
                If .Name = vntTabs(lngTabs, 1) Then
' _
                    'And objWsNew.Name = strCountry
'
                  ' Get the first empty row in the new sheet
                      lngPasteRow = objWsNew.Cells.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row + 1

                  ' Pasting a range into a same sized range is much faster than
                  ' looping or copy/pasting.
                  objWsNew.Range(objWsNew.Cells(lngPasteRow, cVntFirstCol), _
                      objWsNew.Cells(cLngLastRow + lngPasteRow - cLngFirstRow, _
                      cVntLastCol)) = _
                  .Range(.Cells(cLngFirstRow, cVntFirstCol), _
                      .Cells(cLngLastRow, cVntLastCol)).Value2
                      objWsNew.Name = strCountry

                End If
              Next

            End With

          Next
        ojbWbEach.Close False
Exit_Loop:
          Set ojbWbEach = Nothing
          strFile = Dir
        Loop
        End If
    Next lngCountries

  Set objWsEach = Nothing
  Set objWsNew = Nothing
  Set ojbWbEach = Nothing
  Set objWbMaster = Nothing

  Call Module2.clean
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What it does is that it also creates extra blank worksheets which I have to clean up with the sub clean.

Answer (score -1):

This is a code from my consolidator maybe you can get an idea.

```
   Dim lRow As Long
   Dim LastRow As Long
   lRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
   lRow = lRow + 100
   LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row, 9)
   LastRow = LastRow + 1
   sht1.Range("A10:Q" & lRow).Copy
   sht2.Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial

   Dim rowL As Long
   rowL = sht1.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
   sht1.Range("B7").Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("R" & LastRow)
   sht1.Range("D7").Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("S" & LastRow)
```

Comment: The new Excel versions have a little more rows. That's why '"E" & Rows.Count' is used, to make the code work in all versions.